# Google chrome profile in use; browser does not start anymore

Tags: google-chrome

This is the problem when i click on google chrome:

> The profile appears to be in use by process 2747 on host uber-c07b01. If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, delete the file `/home/user/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock` and relaunch Google Chrome.

Comment: So did you try to find that process number with `ps -ef|grep 2747`? And if not did you reboot and remove that file as instructed? Oh and still no reason to use all caps in a title.

Comment: is ther a video to do this I dont wanr to noob around and do thing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome wont start after changing hostname](http://askubuntu.com/questions/476918/google-chrome-wont-start-after-changing-hostname)

Answer (score 6):

First open a terminal (dash->terminal) and type ...

```
ps -ef | grep 2747
```

This command shows processes that are currently running.  Example:

```
ps -ef|grep 2747
rinzwind  2747  3327  0 06:51 ?        00:00:01 chromium-browser                          
rinzwind  6002  5950  0 14:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 2747
```

The 1st resultline is what you are looking for. If this shows anything related to chrome you can then do ...

```
kill -9 2747
```

and try to restart chrome. The kill command kills process 2747. If that fails (ie. it the `ps` command shows nothing) do a ...

```
rm /home/$USER/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock
```

This command actually removes a file so be careful when typing (so do a copy paste ;) )
and try to restart chrome.

If both fail you can also do a reboot before you try to open the browser.