# Google Chrome wont start after changing hostname

Tags: google-chrome

I tried to start google chrome in terminal several times, and I keep receiving the following message:

```
... :ERROR:process_singleton_linux.cc(309)] The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process (8629) on another computer ("previous name of the computer").  Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted.  If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.
... :ERROR:simple_message_box_views.cc(208)] Unable to show a dialog outside the UI thread message loop: Google Chrome - The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process (8629) on another computer ("previous name of the computer").  Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted.  If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google chrome profile in use; browser does not start anymore](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297397/google-chrome-profile-in-use-browser-does-not-start-anymore)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This looks like [Chrome bug #367048 -   Cannot start chrome after changing hostname](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367048), try:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/Singleton*
```

Comment: This helped me out after the same error, all after a change of the hostname of the workstation which this was happening on.

Comment: On Raspbian: `rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/Singleton*`

Comment: Using Ubuntu with temp/non-user profile: `rm -rf /tmp/.config/chromium/Singleton*`

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock` was enough for me

Comment: Thanks! It is still saving lives nearly 8 years later. I faced this problem right after an installation of Chrome on an Ubuntu 22.04 distro.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using newer Ubuntu like 20.04, then you must delete files in different path because you probably using snap packages:

```
rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Singleton*
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on brave not launching after changing hostname on ubuntu 22.o4

Solution

Remove Profile Lock:
Navigate to the directory where your Brave profile is stored. This location varies depending on your operating system:

```
On Windows: C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\User Data\
On macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/
On Linux: ~/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/
```

Look for a file named LOCK or lockfile and delete it. This file is what Brave uses to lock the profile.

This worked for me  `rm -rf SingletonLock`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `rm` and it didn't work, so I checked

```
ls into ~/.config/google
```

and

```
ls ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/
```

and found no singleton files, but the following worked as it is a new system and `ls` found the file

```
rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Singleton*
```